# Meteor atmosphere package source

Tags: meteor, atmosphere

Am I naive or is there really no way to download the source of a meteor package as the project was originally created?

```
(function () {

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                                                                                            //
// packages/iron:router/lib/route.js                                                          //
//                                                                                            //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                                                                                              //
var Url = Iron.Url;                                                                           // 1
var MiddlewareStack = Iron.MiddlewareStack;                                                   // 2
var assert = Iron.utils.assert;                                                               // 3
                                                                                              // 4
/*****************************************************************************/               // 5
/* Both */                                                                                    // 6
/*****************************************************************************/               // 7
```

Everything I download seems to be been processed through some kind of preprocessor.  It seems to all be there and in order but what's the deal?  Is there a way to ask for the unprocessed source?

Comment: Usually there's a github link on the package atmosphere page where you can access the raw source code.

Comment: "The point of Isobuild is to simplify the process of building modern applications: applications that run multiple processes (such as clients and servers) in multiple environments (such as browsers, mobile devices, and node.js under Unix). Without Isobuild, this process is way too complicated and requires expert-level knowledge of each environment."

https://www.meteor.com/isobuild

Answer (score 0):

You can download the package from the git repository of that package.
For editing the package just copy the  repository to packages folder.
Don't forgot to add package name in package file.